# MySQL GROUP BY HAVING returns nothing

Tags: mysql, group-by, opencart, having

I have many categories with the same name and parent in my Opencart database (duplicates). Need to find all of them. That's my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM
     (SELECT `oc_category`.category_id,
             `oc_category`.parent_id,
             `oc_category_description`.name
      FROM   `oc_category`, `oc_category_description`
      WHERE  `oc_category`.category_id = `oc_category_description`.category_id
     ) cats
GROUP BY `cats`.parent_id, `cats`.name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

But this query returns nothing. Please tell me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Could you check if the inner query actually returns duplicated cats.parent_id, cats.name?

Comment: Yes. it returns many duplicates that are differs only by category_id

Comment: Seems nothing wrong with your query, can you provide show create table info and some set of data?

Comment: Yes, it returns not records, let me check...

Comment: I think your query doesn't have any mistake. i) Could you post inner query's output? ii) please compare `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT cats.parent_id, cats.name)` and `SELECT COUNT(*)` I think these counts are same.

Comment: InoS Heo, yes. These counts are same. I don't understand how it can be so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problem with the query, it does work, check this out:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3d170/4

Please fiddle with that and populate it with the data which produces no records, and add it to your question.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/757a47/1 it does work.
But not in PhpMyAdmin.
Now I noticed: MySQL server version - 5.1.73

Comment: I would triple check the data that the inner query returns in my server, may be an ´echo´ or ´print´ to debug, otherwise it would be the biggest bug on a very mature product...

Comment: Uhhh. Thanks a lot to Roberto and InoS Heo!
I found problem: names are not the same. These category names looks the same but:

SELECT MD5( name ) 
FROM  `oc_category_description` 
WHERE category_id =1682
OR category_id =1686

returns two different hashes:
ff75716d820ec260fabc3cc09f97ca60
dd03260beb77782496d106be5c0d9baf

Thanks to all!